# Check the condition for figure position placement on that page?

Tags: floats, captions

I have created a macro to fit a caption on side of the figure (side caption),

1. when figure is on top of the page, the caption should align on the
   top of the figure
2. when figure is on bottom of the page, the caption should align on the bottom of the figure

I have checked with the option `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@fps}{!t}}{}{\vfill}`, when iam giving the figure placement option `!t`, always working on else part only

how to check the condition when figure is on top or bottom?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen,color,showframe}
\definecolor{grayten}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}


\makeatletter
\newdimen\tempdimb
\newif\ifsidecap
\newdimen\captionwidth
\newcommand{\processfigure}[3]{%
                \begingroup
                \def\@captype{figure}%
                \let\@makecaption\@figuremakecaption%
                \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{#1}%
                \global\@tempdima\wd\@tempboxa%
                \global\tempdimb\ht\@tempboxa%
                 \ifdim\@tempdima>.8\textwidth%
                    \global\sidecapfalse%
                       {\centering#1\par}%
                        \caption{#2\ifx!#3!\else{\ #3}\fi}%
                 \else%
                        \global\sidecaptrue%
                        \vbox to 0pt{#1}%\vskip-\lastskip%
                        \caption{#2\ifx!#3!\else{\ #3}\fi}%
                 \fi%

                \endgroup\global\sidecapfalse}
                
\long\def\@figuremakecaption#1#2{\ifsidecap\else\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\fi%
                                 \begingroup%
                                 \small
                                  \ifsidecap%
                                    \removelastskip\nointerlineskip%
                                    \captionwidth\textwidth%
                                    \advance\captionwidth-\@tempdima%
                                    \advance\captionwidth-1pc%gutter space
                                      \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill%
                                                \vbox to \tempdimb{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@fps}{!t}}{}{\vfill}%%%%checking whether figure is on top
                                                \hsize\captionwidth%
                                                {\raggedright%
                                                    \leavevmode\raggedright\textbf{#1:}\enspace#2\vphantom{pjQ}\par
                                                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@fps}{!t}}{\vfill}{}
                                                    }}%
                                        }%
                                    \else%
                                        \raggedright\textbf{#1:}\enspace#2\vphantom{pjQ}\par
                                    \fi%
                                    \endgroup}                
\makeatother


\begin{document}


For measuring time, the horizontal gnomon is inserted into the hole above the scale meant for the current solar month and the staff turned slowly towards the sun so that the gnomon throws its shadow exactly on the scale below. Where the end of the shadow touches the numbered scale, the number indicates in the forenoon the that have elapsed since the sunrise, and in the afternoon, the number of that are to elapse up to sunset.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\processfigure{{\color{grayten}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{15pc}}}{George Cotton's signature of July 1886 for the replacement
spring in McCabe 360. \copyright\ National Maritime Museum (ZAA0213). Photo
by Jonathan Betts}{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!b]
\processfigure{{\color{grayten}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{15pc}}}{George Cotton's signature of July 1886 for the replacement
spring in McCabe 360. \copyright\ National Maritime Museum (ZAA0213). Photo
by Jonathan Betts}{}
\end{figure}


Compared with these, the Indian versions are much longer, ranging between 1,100 to 1,550mm. Instead of twelve separate scales for the twelve solar months, they usually have eight scales, employing one common scale for two solar months which are at equal distance from the equinoxes. The scales are not divided by continuous curves, but by straight lines unconnected with those on the adjacent column. In other words, these are cruder imitations of those produced in the Islamic world and in Europe. Obviously the idea of the column dial came from the Islamic world   we cannot identify the exact process of transmission   but the Sanskrit authors merely borrowed the name, not the principle feature, namely marking the hours on the different scales by continuous curves.

The extant specimens of Indian column dials are of three types: those made of metal or ivory, those made of wood on which scales are painted, and those made of timber on which the scales are carved. There exist just two specimens of the first group. The first is an exquisitely crafted steel column dial in the museum of the History of Science, Oxford, 95.6 cm, with all the scale lines, numbers and decorative patterns inlaid in gold (Figure. 2). It is topped with an ornate finial and the other end terminates in a sharply polished blade. It must have been created for some prince in Rajasthan. The other, made of ivory, is also of excellent workmanship, with a beautifully carved finial at the top and an ornate end at






\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the figure is formatted before it is placed, there is no way to tell.  OTOH, you might be able to store the information in the aux file using tikzmark.

Comment: If I understood it, you need to generate some random text to try your macro? If so, look at the `lipsum` package

Comment: the figure is fully typeset before it is known what page it will be placed on and whether it will be top or bottom, so you can not do a simple test of any macros within the figure. Somewhere on this site I have an answer that gives different formatting for different float areas  (by saving multiple versions of the figure and deciding at position time which to use (like marginpar choosing left or right margin format) faied to find it just now....

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to deal will all the details of your MWE, but here is a test using TikZ to determine whether a float is a top float or bottom float.  Note that this test assumes `\topfraction+\bottomfraction<1`.

Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\iftopfloat
\newcommand{\checkfloat}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \path (current page text area.north);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}%
  \ifdim \y<\topfraction\textheight \global\topfloattrue   \else \global\topfloatfalse \fi}}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\checkfloat
\iftopfloat Top Float \else Bottom Float \fi
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\checkfloat
\iftopfloat Top Floar \else Bottom Float \fi
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]% not on smae page
\centering
\checkfloat
\iftopfloat Top Float \else Bottom Float \fi
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]% not on same page
\centering
\checkfloat
\iftopfloat Top Floar \else Bottom Float \fi
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```