# Find out if a figure is positioned h, t, b, or p

Tags: floats, positioning

Is there a way to find out and use the positioning choice (**h**ere, **t**op, **b**ottom, **p**age) made for some `figure`?

```
Please spend a few minutes to admire 
\edef\mypos{\thepositioningchoicethatwasusedfor{myfig}}
\ifx\mypos h the following image:\fi
\ifx\mypos t \ref{myfig} at the top of page \pageref{myfig}.\fi
\ifx\mypos b \ref{myfig} at the bottom of page \pageref{myfig}.\fi
\ifx\mypos p \ref{myfig} residing on its own page \pageref{myfig}.\fi
\begin{figure}[htbp]
...
\label{myfig}
\end{figure}
```

I suppose I could play with `\zref` to make good guesses, but perhaps there is already something ready-made?

Comment: \label only records \@currentlabel (counter value), \@currentlabelname (varies), \@currentHref (hyperref target) and the page number.  The placement options are implemented a bit flags in the float queue, but the hard part would be figuring out which insert corresponds to the given figure.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587069/check-the-condition-for-figure-position-placement-on-that-page and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425892/place-figure-at-bottom-of-this-page-or-the-top-of-the-next-page?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C53.9480

Comment: It may be better to consider wordings of the following kind: "Figure X above/below" or "Figure Y on the previous/following page" or "Figure Z on page z"... rather than highlighting the location on the specific page; figures will have captions, which readers should... well.. read. [`varioref`](//ctan.org/pkg/varioref) can help with the wording choices, as can [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s modules.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to run twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savefps}[1]% #1 = label name
{\bgroup
  \edef\@currentlabel{\number\@tempcnta}%
  \label{#1}%
\egroup}

\newcommand{\checkh}[3]{% #1 = bit flags, #2 = true, #3 = false
  \@tempcntb=#1\relax
  \ifodd\@tempcntb #2\relax
  \else #3\relax
  \fi}

\newcommand{\checkt}[3]{% #1 = bit flags, #2 = true, #3 = false
  \@tempcntb=#1\relax
  \divide\@tempcntb by 2
  \ifodd\@tempcntb #2\relax
  \else #3\relax
  \fi}


\newcommand{\checkb}[3]{% #1 = bit flags, #2 = true, #3 = false
  \@tempcntb=#1\relax
  \divide\@tempcntb by 4
  \ifodd\@tempcntb #2\relax
  \else #3\relax
  \fi}

\newcommand{\checkp}[3]{% #1 = bit flags, #2 = true, #3 = false
  \@tempcntb=#1\relax
  \divide\@tempcntb by 8
  \ifodd\@tempcntb #2\relax
  \else #3\relax
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\edef\foo{\getrefnumber{test}}% see refcount package
\checkh{\foo}{h}{not h}\par
\checkt{\foo}{t}{not t}\par
\checkb{\foo}{b}{not b}\par
\checkp{\foo}{p}{not p}\par

\begin{figure}[hp]
\savefps{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```