# How to put a halmos into a caption of a H-placed figure when using svmono?

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, theorems, sv-classes

Let's say you want to put a theorem-like–environment—ending symbol on the last line of a non-floating Figure.  So far, we tried to use the code we already have for putting the symbol after `\end{center}`:

```
\documentclass{svmono}% V5.10 from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs .  For testing purposes, I hope, book would do as well.
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{float,placeins}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}
\newcommand*{\textHalmosEndingNonProof}{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol\parfillskip=\z@\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}}
\newlength\lastSkipOfEndCenter
\newcommand*{\textHalmosEndingNonProofAfterCenter}{\setlength\lastSkipOfEndCenter{\lastskip}\removelastskip\nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip\relax}\nopagebreak\textHalmosEndingNonProof\vskip\lastSkipOfEndCenter}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
  Drawing 1
  \caption{A long line as the caption so that you see that the vertical placement of the halmos symbol is by no means ideal, right?}%
\end{figure}%
\textHalmosEndingNonProofAfterCenter
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
  Drawing 2
  \caption{A short caption\textHalmosEndingNonProof}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

As you see from the output

[image: output]

there are several issues here:

1. In the caption of Fig. 1.1, ■ overlaps the text
2. In the caption of Fig. 1.1, ■ is a bit too low.
3. In the caption of Fig. 1.2, ■ is too much left, whereas it should be right-aligned.

How to put a block-terminating symbol or string (we use the halmos ∎ for terminating non-proofs and “q.e.d.“ for terminating proofs) into a caption properly™?  Let's also assume that you'd like to avoid using concrete lengths, such as `-1ex` in `\vspace{-1ex}`, because your fonts and distances are subject to change in the editing or publishing process. Btw., using `marginnote` is a no-go (because this package incurs an unrelated overlap in our larger, non-minimal example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{svmono}% V5.10 from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs .  For testing purposes, I hope, book would do as well.
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{float,placeins}

\newcommand{\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
% doing nothing here \FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
  Drawing 1
  \caption[cap with no halmos]{A long line as the caption so that you see that the vertical placement of the halmos symbol is by no means ideal, right?%
\penalty-100\mbox{}\quad\nobreak\hfill\nobreak\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol}%
\end{figure}%

% doing nothing here \FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
  Drawing 2
  \caption[cap with no halmos]{A short caption%
\penalty-100\mbox{}\quad\nobreak\hfill\nobreak\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot! You're saving my day. Second, I included `\FloatBarrier` simply to show that this is an excerpt from a larger, non-minimal example in which these commands would be included to maintain the total order of all Figures, floating and non-floating ones. Yes, it is true that in certain situations we don't need `\FloatBarrier` (e.g., inside a series of H-placed figures if only the first one has `\FloatBarrier` or if no floating stuff has been issued so far). Yes, I read your advice not to use floats (and still, sometimes we have to).

Comment: It's more or less `\qed` from `amsthm`  (I just looked now, not when posting the answer:-)

Comment: O.k. As for my version, I don't know where it came from (apparently, not directly from QED.sty but close to it). By the way, why have you given the caption additional short titles in square brackets?

Comment: Moreover, there is a fourth issue I see just now: the halmos appears `\small`.  I'm unsure whether this is wanted. To have a standard-size halmos, would a `\normalsize\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol` do or should we brace it via `{\normalsize\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol}` or do something else?

Comment: @GeekestGeek brace (or put the font size and braces in the def of the symbol

Comment: Thanks! Or should we better say `\begingroup\normalsize\textHalmosEndingNonProofSymbol\endgroup`?

Comment: same thing as you are not in math