# How to move a q.e.d. / halmos / tombstone in the caption of a H-placed figure to the right margin when using article?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, article, qed

Continuing [How to put a halmos into a caption of a H-placed figure when using svmono?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654683), what to do when you're using the class `article` rather than `svmono`?  Running `pdflatex` on

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\qedSymbol}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}%% or \boxempty,\square, etc.
\newcommand*{\qedOne}{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\qedSymbol\parfillskip=\z@\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}}
\newcommand{\qedTwo}{\penalty-100\mbox{}\quad\nobreak\hfill\nobreak\qedSymbol}% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654684 .
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line contains a nicely placed \qedOne

\begin{figure}[H]%\centering% We usually center the contents.
  Figure contents
  \caption{This caption contains a wrongly placed \qedOne}
\end{figure}

This long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line long long line also contains a nicely placed \qedTwo

\begin{figure}[H]%\centering% We usually center the contents.
  Figure contents
  \caption{This caption also contains a wrongly placed \qedTwo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output]

As you see, the tombstone symbols in the captions are NOT at the right margin. How to bring these tombstones to the right?  (No, please do NOT suggest `\marginnote`, `\marginpar`, or `\marginline`, since our nonminimal example writes text into the margins and loads some packages influencing/redefining these commands. Also fixed, unflexible solutions in the vein of `\hskip10em\qedSymbol` are frowned upon, as they break when the text or margins or font change; we are interested in more flexible ways.  Also do NOT use the `caption` package (as it breaks other stuff in a non-minimal example).)

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that this figure is actually intended to end a proof?  If that is true, it should almost certainly not be allowed to float, so `figure` should not be used, but its contents inserted in place, with `\captionof` used to place the caption.  Then, the tombstone can be placed, as usual, at the end of the proof, but raised the necessary amount to coincide with the baseline of the caption.  I've done this in the context of `amsmath`, but not under different conditions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Right. I oversimplified the MWE earlier. I've just updated it. As for `\captionof`, I'm reading the documentation of `capt-of` now.

Comment: Oops!  I said `amsmath` in an earlier comment.  I really meant `amsthm`.  (I seem to be catching bad habits from so many other people in this forum.  I really do know better.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will work anywhere of your non MWE. The third caption have some ending "x" to show the result when the last line cannot fit any more text, so even a single "x" will cause a linebreak as showed in the 4th figure.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\qed{%
\nobreak\mbox{ }\nobreak\hfill%
\hspace{\linewidth minus .999\linewidth}%
\rule{1ex}{1ex}\par}
\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[1][1]  \qed
\lipsum[1][1-2]  \qed
\lipsum[1][1-4]  \qed
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{\lipsum[3][1]\qed}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}\caption{\lipsum[3][1-3]\qed}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}\caption{\lipsum[3][1-3] xxxxxxxx\qed}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}\caption{\lipsum[3][1-3] xxxxxxxxx\qed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! All the text of your caption of Fig.1 except the halmos is left-aligned, i.e., adjacent to the left page margin. What we need instead is that all the caption without the halmos be centered as usual, and that the halmos itself be right-aligned, i.e., that it be adjacent to the right page margin.

Comment: Then, `\qed`  cannot part of the  short centered `\caption`. A workaround could be `\caption{\lipsum[3][1]}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\qed`